# HSQLDB/Java PrimaryKey and Binary Keys

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I created a simple table in java using hsqldb with the following code

```
s.execute("CREATE TABLE Testtable(id VARCHAR(13) PRIMARY KEY, counter INTEGER)");
```

Now I want to fill that table with id's being binarystrings e.g. 010 or 101 etc but when I execute the following lines of code

```
statement.execute("INSERT into Testtable Values(0,0)");
statement.execute("INSERT into Testtable Values(00,0)");
statement.execute("INSERT into Testtable Values(000,0)");
statement.execute("INSERT into Testtable Values(0000,0)");
```

I get the error that my id's are not unique. Apparently hsqldb doesn't see the difference between 0 and 00 but since it'sdatatype is a VARCHAR should they be handled as strings? "0" and "00" are not the same or what am I missing?

Comment: that insert is inserting integers not strings, use prepared statements

Comment: thank you I will take a look at prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting 0 into the primary key column (0, 00, 000, etc. are all 0).

If you enclose the values in single quotes they are treated as strings and '0' is considered different from '00'.

```
statement.execute("INSERT into Testtable Values('0',0)");
statement.execute("INSERT into Testtable Values('00',0)");
statement.execute("INSERT into Testtable Values('000',0)");
statement.execute("INSERT into Testtable Values('0000',0)");
```